# How to disable Click event on Image View when process is going on at first click

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have grid containing images. On click of images, downloading of book starts. If the download is in progress and if i am clicking that image only the download getting started. Due to this the resultant file is corrupted. The downloading task has been put on the onClick event of image. I have tried to make first image clickable false then setEnable false. but both the way didn't work for me. The image click is working even download is in progress. Please guide. 
For details,Here is my codes:

```
   public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ImageView imageView;
    private Context context;
    private int item;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    GridViewAdapter(Context c, int griditem) {
        this.context = c;
        this.item = griditem;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return bank.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
      return bank.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        View grid;

        Display display = ((WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        int orientation = display.getOrientation();

        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(context);
            grid = layoutInflater.inflate(item, null);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        final TextView title = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.mgntitle);
        title.setText(bank.get(position).getTitle());
        imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) grid
                .findViewById(R.id.progress);
        final ImageView downloadmark = (ImageView) grid
                .findViewById(R.id.downloadmark);
        String pdfLink = bank.get(position).getPdfLink();
        String filename = pdfLink.substring(pdfLink.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        final File targetDir = new File(fileLocation + filename);

        if(targetDir.exists()){
            downloadmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!targetDir.exists()) {
                    if (isInternetConnected()) {
                        map.put(bank.get(position).getTitle(), progress);
                        new DownloadPdfFile(GridDisplayActivity.this, bank
                                .get(position).getPdfLink(), progress,
                                downloadmark, imageView).execute();
                    } else {
                        setAlertBox("You are not connected to Internet. Please switch your connection ON to be able to Downlaod Bespoken Magazines");
                    }
                } else {

                     Toast.makeText(context, "File exists",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Book opening intent has to be fried here
                }
            }

        });



        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                bank.get(position).getCoverPages(), 0, bank.get(position)
                        .getCoverPages().length));

        if (!getPrefName(filename).equalsIgnoreCase("NA")) {
            if (new File(fileLocation + filename).exists()) {
                // tag.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
                 downloadmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("BESPOKEN_PREF",
                                MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString(filename, "NA");
                editor.commit();

            }
        }

        if (new File(fileLocation + filename).exists()) {
            if (!getPrefName(filename).equalsIgnoreCase("NA")) {
                // tag.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
            //  downloadmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

            }

        }

        return grid;

    }
}

private String getPrefName(String name) {
    SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("BESPOKEN_PREF",
            MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    return pref.getString(name, "NA");
}

private void saveBookName(String title) {
    SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("BESPOKEN_PREF",
            MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString(title, title);
    editor.commit();
}

private boolean isInternetConnected() {
    connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    mMobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    return mWifi.isConnected() || mMobile.isConnected();
}

private class DownloadPdfFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private int progressupdate;
    String link;
    ProgressBar progress;
    ImageView cover;
    String file;
    ImageView dwnloadmark;

    public DownloadPdfFile(GridDisplayActivity activity, String link,
            ProgressBar progressbar, ImageView dwnmrk, ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.setEnabled(false);
        progress = progressbar;
        this.link = link;
        this.cover = imageView;
        this.dwnloadmark = dwnmrk;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        cover.setEnabled(false);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        file = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        InputStream is = null;
        long startTime = 0;
        int count;
        // DownloadFromUrl(link, fileLocation + file,progress);
        try {

            URL url = new URL(link);
            File dir = new File(fileLocation);
            if (dir.exists()) {

            } else {
                Log.i("",
                        "---------targetDir not .exists()----------------4");
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation + file);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        Log.d("ImageManager",
                "download ready in"
                        + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                        + " sec");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog) {
        progressupdate = prog[0];
        progress.setProgress(progressupdate);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dwnloadmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // tag.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        saveBookName(file);
        cover.setEnabled(true);
    }

}



class DoBackgroundTask extends CustomAsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    private static final String TAG = "DoBackgroundTask";

    private int progressupdate;
    String link;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    ImageView dwnloadmark;
    ImageView cover;
    String file;
    GridDisplayActivity activity;

    public DoBackgroundTask(GridDisplayActivity activity, String link,
            ProgressBar progressbar, ImageView dwnmrk, ImageView img) {
        super(activity);
        img.setEnabled(false);
        this.activity = activity;
        progress = progressbar;
        this.link = link;
        this.dwnloadmark = dwnmrk;
        this.cover = img;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        cover.setEnabled(false);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityDetached() {
        if (progress != null) {
             //progress.setActivated(false);
            // progress = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityAttached() {

        //progress.setActivated(true);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.setProgress(progressupdate);
        // showProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        file = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        InputStream is = null;
        long startTime = 0;
        int count;
        // DownloadFromUrl(link, fileLocation + file,progress);
        try {

            URL url = new URL(link);
            File dir = new File(fileLocation);
            if (dir.exists()) {

            } else {

                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation + file);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        Log.d("ImageManager",
                "download ready in"
                        + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                        + " sec");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog) {

        progressupdate = prog[0];

        if (mActivity != null) {
            progress.setProgress(progressupdate);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Progress updated while no Activity was attached.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dwnloadmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
        cover.setEnabled(true);
        saveBookName(file);

        if (mActivity != null) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "AsyncTask finished",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private boolean _buttonPressed = false;


    .....

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(_buttonPressed){
               return;
            }
            _buttonPressed = true;
            .........

    ..... 


    private class DownloadPdfFile extends AsyncTask<....> {
          .....
          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(....) {
              _buttonPressed = false;    
          } 
          ..... 
    }
}
```

Comment: I like appserv's answer, but I would suggest two things.  First, you should absolutely provide some visual feedback so the user knows that something is loading in the background.  I would grey out the button and overlay the word "Loading..." or perhaps a pinwheel animation.  Second, you should use button.setEnabled() at the same places you set _buttonPressed.

Comment: @Edward The widget that i am using here is image rather than a button. I have implemented horizontal progress bar with status update when downloading is going on. My problem was the image is clickable even after it has been clicked once. Because of that the downloading is starting again and corrupted file is downloading.

Comment: You should still be able to make the image button non-clickable.  Look into setClickable() or setEnabled().  If all else fails, appserv's answer is still a good one.  Excellent work, implementing a progress bar, BTW; sounds like an excellent UI idea.